# Миграция Windows из VmWare в KVM

Tags: linux, windows, vmware, kvm, qemu

Есть виртуальная машина на VmWare. Виртуальную машину экспортировал из VmWare. .vmdk был конвертирован в .qemu

Запустил на другом железе:

```
/mnt/ssd/WIN7$ virt-install \
 --name WIN7 \
 --ram 16384 \
 --cpu host \
 --vcpus=6 \
 --os-type=windows \
 --boot hd \
 --disk "/mnt/ssd/WIN7/WIN7.qemu",bus=virtio,format=qcow2,cache=writeback \
 --graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0
```

Подключаюсь по VNC, а Windows не грузится. Предлагает только режим восстановления. Есть ли какие-либо настройки в KVM для эмуляции железа?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/423103/126632

Comment: Дрова на винт и контроллер винтов грохнул?